# How do I make Topshelf log exceptions to Elmah

Tags: elmah, topshelf

Topshelf is a great little library for wrapping up a windows service.  I'm trying to find out if I can configure it to log out exceptions to elmah.  From what I can tell it has an internal handler for unhandled exceptions.

http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/logging.html

Would it be a case of writing a new logger and submitting a pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the existing logging implementations in the repository to get started. No one has asked for ELMAH before but I don't see why you'd be the only person interested.

You can also just create a new repository, it will be a new nuget package anyways.

Comment: I'll give it a bash tonight or tomorrow!

Comment: I've just submitted my pull request https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/pull/159